# Return object with dynamic keys in AQL

Tags: arangodb

Can I return something like:

```
{
"c/12313" = 1,
"c/24223" = 2,
"c/43423" = 3,
...
}
```

from an AQL query? The idea is something like (this non-working code):

```
for c in my_collection
return { c._id : c.sortOrder }
```

where `sortOrder` is some property on my documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have [dynamic attribute names](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Fundamentals/DataTypes.html#objects--documents):

```
LET key = "foo"
LET value = "bar"
RETURN { [ key ]: value } // { "foo": "bar" }
```

An expression to compute the attribute key has to be wrapped in `[` square brackets `]`, like in JavaScript.

This doesn't return quite the desired result however:

```
FOR c IN my_collection
  RETURN { [ c._id ]: c.sortOrder }

[
  { "c/12313": 1 },
  { "c/24223": 2 },
  { "c/43423": 3 },
  ...
]
```

To not return separate objects for every key, [MERGE()](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/Document.html#merge) and a subquery are required:

```
RETURN MERGE(
  FOR c IN my_collection
    RETURN { [ c._id ]: c.sortOrder }
)

[
  {
    "c/12313": 1,
    "c/24223": 2,
    "c/43423": 3,
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe add a link from the AQL chapter on the `return` statement to the data type chapter for object?

Comment: Extended the docs: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/d07c3c848cf9754163d561477f916805077b88d5

Comment: This is quite impressive - the ability to run a FOR loop _inside_ the MERGE.

Comment: The return is an object in an array. The array is unnecessary. Is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: Results are always encapsulated in an array, you can't remove it.